# Calculate integer powers with a given loop invariant

Tags: algorithm

I need to derive an algorithm in C++ to calculate integer powers m^n that uses the loop invariant r = y^n and the loop condition y != m.

I tried using the instruction y= y+1 to advance, but I don´t know how to obtain (y+1)^n from y^n, and it shouldn't be difficult to find . So, probably, this isn't the correct path to follow

Could you help me to derive the program?

EDIT: this is a problem from the subject Data Structures and Algorithms. The difficulty ( if there is at all) shouldn't be mathematic.

EDIT2: Just to clarify, the difficulty of the problem is using the invariant y^n and loop condition y != m. If I vary the  n I'm not achieving that

Comment: *I don´t know how to obtain (y+1)^n from y^n* strikes me as a mathematical problem, not a programming problem, and therefore off-topic.

Comment: You need y^(n+1), not (y+1)^n. I hope this solves the problem for you. If not, please [edit] your question and *add your existing code* to clarify.

Comment: as @anatolyg writes, you are using the wrong step increment: you want m^(y+1). Edit your question as anatoly writes if you want a real answer. Otherwise, if the question is not useful for future readers, it will probably be closed.

Comment: Come on tucuxi, the answer to what you are suggesting is much easier. We already designed the algorithm in class with the invariant m^x (varying x), but now I have been asked to do it with y^n (varying y). Do you think it's not possible?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: this is a problem in programming methodology, i.e. somewhere between theory and practice.

Comment: What is the range of possible inputs?  I can do this if you have a limit on the size of m^n

Comment: @MattTimmermans I don't think there is  a limit size of the data. Anyway, I'm interested in what you have to say, suppose 0<= m,n <= 10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given **w** and **P** such that **2^w > m**, **P > 2^(wn)**, and **2^((P-1)/2) = -1 mod P**,

then **2** is a generator mod **P**, and there will be some **x** such that **2^x = m mod P**, so:

```
if (m<=1 || n==1)
    return m;
if (n==0)
    return 1;

let y = 2;
let r = 1<<n;

while(y!=m)
{
    y = (y*2)%P;
    r = (r*(1<<n))%P;
}
return r;
```

Unless your function needs to produce bignum results, you can just pick the largest **P** that fits into an integer in your language.

Comment: Nice. How can we compute P?

Comment: In fact, I'm looking for something simpler. But your idea is really interesting

Comment: "The difficulty ( if there is at all) shouldn't be mathematic." This algorithm relies on number theory, which is rather advanced mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

There is no useful relation between `(y+1)^n` and `y^n` (you can write `(y+1)^n = (√(y^n)+1)^n` or `(y+1)^n = (1+1/y)^n y^n`, but this leads you nowhere).

If `y` was factored, you could exploit `(a.b)^n = (a^n).(b^n)`, but you would need a table of the `n`th powers of the primes.

I can't see an answer that makes sense.

---

You can also think of the Binomial theorem,

```
(y+1)^n = y^n + n y^(n-1) + n(n-1)/2 y^(n-2) + ... 1
```

but this is worse than anything: you need to compute `n` binomial coefficients, and update all powers of `y` from `0` to `n`. The total cost of the computation would be ridiculously high.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought of all that. Those don't solve the problem. Thanks for the try, anyway